# Inherit problem in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my web application i copy and paste the code from other site to in my page also the source code starting form 
 when i run the application it is giving the error like this

### Server Error in '/DomainIV' Application.

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

Source Error:

Line 1:  using System;
Line 2:  using System.Data;
Line 3:  using System.Web;

Source File: c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DomainIV\WhoIs.aspx.cs    Line: 1

this is my problem help me thank u.

Comment: Can you post the code of both asp.net page and code-behind class ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your aspx page there will be the following at the top:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Test.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestApp.Test" Title="Untitled Page" %>
```

In your .cs file your class will be defined like:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
```

Make sure the inherits property in the aspx page matches the class definition in the .cs file.  In the example above it is 'TestApp.Test' in the inherits property and the class must have the same namespace and classname TestApp and Test.

You probably copied the whole contents of one of the files and now the two pieces no longer match up.

Comment: Additionally, make sure no other pages (accidentally) try to inherit a class from the same code behind file.

Comment: I had made copies of a pair of aspx and aspx.cs files as backup and left them in the project folder.  Even though these files were not part of the project they were still being processed when I would build the project and causing this error.  Removing the files from the folder fixed the error.  Thanks to Protector one (+1).

Comment: Protector, isn't part of the purpose of code-behind files supposed to be reusable code?  Shouldn't you /want/ multiple pages inheriting from the same class?

Answer (score 1):

My advice, create the new page with the same file name as the source.
Then copy and paste the codes into the new pages (APSX and code-behind). Works for me everytime.

Answer (score 1):

In aspx page, there will be

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

And in .cs page

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page{}
```

Inherits attribute and the class name both should be same.
Hope this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your ASPX file, make sure the @Page declaration has an Inherits attribute that matches the full class name of the class in your code behind file.  This declaration is usually the first line of the ASPX file.  Also make sure that the class in your code behind file inherits System.Web.UI.Page and that it is not a sealed class.