# ASP.NET Error About "Inherits" attribute, even though it's correct?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Having a really strange issue at the moment with an ASP.NET site I'm currently building.

At the moment, I'm writting the HTML and CSS for a page called Dashboard.aspx. But when I go to view the page in a browser, half the time it throws up this error:

> ASPNET: Make sure that the class
>   defined in this code file matches the
>   'inherits' attribute, and that it
>   extends the correct base class (e.g.
>   Page or UserControl).

I've checked the Inherits attribute on the .aspx page, and it matches the Partial Class held in the VB code of Dashboard.aspx.vb file.

When I refresh, it will always come up with this error. Then after a minute or two, it will load fine with no problems. I had a quick look on Google and I couldn't find an answer to this issue.

I have also changed the name of the partial class (and the content placeholder on the .aspx file, thinking that may have caused a conflict) and nothing I do seems to fix it.

Could anyone shed any light on what's going on?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Make sure the inherits property in the
>   aspx page matches the class definition
>   in the .cs file. […] the inherits
>   property and the class must have the
>   same namespace and classname

(From: [Inherit problem in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671747/inherit-problem-in-asp-net))

Additionally, make sure no other pages (accidentally) try to inherit a class from the same code behind file.