# Office 2010 VSTO AddIn Not loading

Tags: vsto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to troubleshoot a VSTO addin that does not load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load)

I have a VSTO 2010 Office 2010 Outlook Add-In. It works installing on my dev machine and on a standard user machine and fails on another. When i run outlook it says a runtime error occured during the loading of the runtime addin. If i go to the install dir of the addin and run manually the VSTO deployment manifest file, it comes up with the office customization installer wizard and installs the add-in fine, i then run outlook and it works. Any ideas guys?!

I've met the follow pre-reqs:

- .NET 4 / Client profile
- Visual stuio 2010 tools for office runtimes
- Office 2010!
- office 2010 PIAs
- My Add-In
- Reg key to load the VSTO, pointign ti install vsto and | vstolocal
- Installed in Program files so no inclusion list required
- FUll permissions administrator on machine

THanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have you check your VSTO log file? You can do that by adding the following on your system environment variables:

```
NAME: VSTO_LOGALERTS
VALUE: 1
```

There might be an exception error that is why your add-in is not loading.

You can check [this source for more info](http://www.macroview.com.au/support/KnowledgeBase/Pages/20110084.aspx) on VSTO logging and alerts, but in essence you change two environment variable values depending on what you need to do:

> **Displaying VSTO Alert Prompts**
>
> To display each error in a message box, set the
>   VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS variable to 0 (zero). You can suppress the
>   messages by setting the variable to 1 (one).
>
> **Logging VSTO Alerts to a Log file**
>
> To write the errors to a log file, set the `VSTO_LOGALERTS` variable
>   to 1 (one).
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Office creates the log file in the folder that
>   contains the application manifest. The default name is .manifest.log.
>   To stop logging errors, set the variable to 0 (zero).

Comment: nice troubleshooting approach.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to check is whether or not the problem machine is running 64-bit or 32-bit version of Office. I don't mean the machine itself (your AddIn can happily support a mix of 32-bit and 64-bit machines), I mean the Office software.

We were stuck like you trying to figure out why our addin worked in some machines and not others and in the end *the mix of 32 and 64 bit versions of Office itself* turned out to be the problem.

The solution was to get all users onto the same 32 bit version of Office.

Comment: good point. some people don't understand the difference between OS and application bitness. However if you read the question carefully he states that on the machine it fails on, he can run the manifest manually and it works. this means it is not Office 64 bit in this case.

Comment: you're right - i should downvote my own answer!

Comment: lol, no its ok your answer is informative and adds to the general troubleshooting knowledge of those working on this technology stack. I'll +1 you anyway.