# Unable to install Excel 2003 Addin. How to diagnose troubles?

Tags: installation, ms-office, add-in, excel-2003

I have create Excel 2003 addin and installer according with manual http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cristib/archive/2010/11/01/deploying-a-vsto-word-2007-add-in-to-all-users-visual-studio-2008-sp1.aspx

At that time I try to install addin on another machine. Installation pass success, but addin does not work. Excel does not shows any errors, but plugin is not loaded correctly and does not work.

Does it exists any way to diagnose problems with addin?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question.

[How to troubleshoot a VSTO addin that does not load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load)
More info can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269003.aspx