# Outlook 2007 Add-In, LoadBehavior changing to 0

Tags: outlook-2007-addin

I'm developing an add-in for Outlook 2007 (VSTO 4.0, .Net 4.0). Whenever I install on the target machine using an msi all registry settings are correctly set and I can see the add-in listed under the installed add-ins. However, it is listed under inactive and whenever I go to manage the com add-ins and check the box to enable it, it does not stay checked.

I checked the registry setting and the load behavior has changed from 3 to 0, so I close outlook, change it back to 3 and start outlook again. Once again it changes from 3 to 0.

- I'm installing the add-in for all users so the registry is under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
- I have the hotfix for office 2007 to be able to install for all users under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
- The add-in is not listed under the "Disabled Items"
- The Load Behavior is switching from 3 to 0 ( not 2 ) so there are no messages regarding runtime errors
- I've turned on fusion logging but there are no errors showing there either
- I've put logging statements in the startup event but they are not being called which leads me to think the add-in is not even being called so it may be a configuration issue.

I've gone through this article: [Deploying your VSTO add-ins to All Users (Saurabh Bhatia)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/08/deploying-your-vsto-add-ins-to-all-users-saurabh-bhatia.aspx) and the msdn doc referenced in it several times now and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Any help debugging this issue further, or even better, a solution to this issue, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had similar issue. Install Outlook 2007 Service Pack 2 as well as this hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976477

Also make sure you have HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\General\EnableLocalMachineVSTO = 1

For more info visit: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976811

Comment: Yeah, that registry key is exactly what the problem was. I managed to resolve it on the MSDN forums and forgot to update it here. Thanks though for your response!

Answer (score 1):

When I installed Outlook Add-In in client's machine which contains Outlook 2007, our outlook Add-In didn't get enabled. We searched a lot. Finally we concluded as this is not a issue with Outlook Add-In.

Outlook Add-In needs the following in Outlook 2007:

- Microsoft Office Service Pack to Service Pack 2 along with Hot fix
- Microsoft Office Service Pack to Service Pack 3

Installed Microsoft Office Service Pack to Service Pack 2 along with Hot fix or above versions of Service Pack.

Please find the Service Pack 2 Hot fix link below 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976477