# Lost network connection causes Excel to crash

Tags: c#, excel, connection, add-in

My Excel AddIn is written in NetOffice, ExcelDNA, C# 
It calls web service to get data. It takes a while to fetch a large amount of data.
During the process of data fetch, if network connection is lost, then Excel will hung, shows like "not responding". Now if I try to close Excel, it will ask you to close or debug. I simply close it. 
Then when I restart Excel, there is an annoying message box comes up saying
"Excel experienced a serious problem with the 'commodity add-in' add-in. If you have seen this message multiple times, you should disable this add-in and check to see if an update is available. Do you want to disable this add-in?."

I wonder how to handle the situation when connection is lost appropriately?  Thanks

Comment: try/catch your web request.

Comment: The fetch is being done directly to Excel? How abount creating some intermediate data storage in the add-in. Fetch to it and after done, fetch it to excel.

Answer (score 2):

Make the web service call asynchronously, if possible. Most WS will provide async versions and non-async versions of the calls that you can make.

If this is not possible, consider executing the web service data fetch within a separate thread.

In both scenarios, you should put some plumbing code in place to kill the job after a certain period, and probably some means to notify the user that not all is well.

Comment: Indeed - it sounds like the new async UDF support in Excel-DNA is what one needs.

Comment: @Govert could you please post an example of that :)

Comment: There's are examples of simple async functions, using .NET 4 Tasks, using Reactive Extensions (RxExcel) and native F# async UDFs in the Excel-DNA distribution. See https://exceldna.codeplex.com and http://excel-dna.net.

Answer (score 1):

> "Excel experienced a serious problem with the 'XXX add-in' add-in. If
>   you have seen this message multiple times, you should disable this
>   add-in and check to see if an update is available. Do you want to
>   disable this add-in?."

You get this problem when an unhandled exception occurs. Excel will prompt you to disable the Add-In next start up. This can lead users to posts like [this to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load/14698249#14698249).

The pain is worse when you have to support clients using Citrix in non-admin environments. To get around the problem of Excel wanting to diable the add-In you have to add a Global Exception handler so the exception isn't referred back to Excel to avoid prompting users to disable the Add-In.

```
public YouAddInCtrl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event.
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += ApplicationThreadException;
    // Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. 
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += ApplicationUnhandledException;   
}

private void ApplicationThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    addInManager.TopLevelExceptionHandler(e.Exception);
}

private void ApplicationUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    addInManager.TopLevelExceptionHandler((Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
}


// Any exceptions returned to Excel will cause the Addin to be disabled
// So we must swallow them here.
internal void TopLevelExceptionHandler(Exception ex)
{
    var e = new NotificationEventArgs(NotificationEventArgs.NotificationEnum.TopLevelException);
    if (NotifyEventTopLevelException != null)
    {
        if (NotifyEventTopLevelException(ex,e))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:Support@XYZ.com%3e?subject=XYZ%202%20PROD%20Environment%20Problem&body=Hi,%0A%0AIssue:%0A%0ASteps%20to%20Reproduce:"); 
        }
    }

    LogExceptions(ex);
}
```

I would also suggest that you run the WebService request on a different thread, eg:

```
BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
BackgroundWorker1.DoWork += DoWorkExecuteQuery;
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompletedExecuteQuery;


private bool QueryData()
{
    var thinkProgBar = new ThinkingProgressBar();
    thinkProgBar.ShowCancelLink(true);
    thinkProgBar.SetThinkingBar(true);
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(thinkProgBar);
    thinkProgBar.ShowDialog();
    if (thinkProgBar.Tag != null && thinkProgBar.Tag.ToString() == "Cancelled")
    {
        CancelGetDataByFilters();
        thinkProgBar.SetThinkingBar(false);
        return false;
    }
    thinkProgBar.SetThinkingBar(false);
    return true;
}

private void DoWorkExecuteQuery(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    dtQueryData = null;
    e.Result = e.Argument;
    ((ThinkingProgressBar)e.Result).SetThinkingBar(true);
    dtQueryData = WEBSERVICE.GetData();  //CALL YOUR WEBSERVICE HERE
}

private void RunWorkerCompletedExecuteQuery(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var dlg = e.Result as ThinkingProgressBar;
    if (dlg != null) {
        ((ThinkingProgressBar)e.Result).SetThinkingBar(false);
        dlg.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is the ThinkingProgress bar:

```
public partial class ThinkingProgressBar : Form
{
    private System.DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    public ThinkingProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void lblClose_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Tag = "Cancelled";
        this.Hide();
    }
    public void ShowCancelLink(bool show)
    {
        lblClose.Visible = show;
    }

    public void SetThinkingBar(bool on)
    {
        if (on)
        {
            lblTime.Text = "0:00:00";
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var diff = new TimeSpan();
        diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);
        lblTime.Text = diff.Hours + ":" + diff.Minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + diff.Seconds.ToString("00");
        lblTime.Invalidate();
    }
}
```