# Customised Outlook Add-in installs properly on some machine whereas in some it goes into Inactive state

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in, outlook-addin

We developed an Outlook Add-In for Win 7 with SP1 and .NET Framework 4.0 as a prerequisite. It gets install perfectly on some machine without any hiccup but in other machines (same configuration, Win 7 & SP1) the add-in goes into the 'inactive' state and doesnt load while outlook start-up.

While installing there are no issues or error message getting displayed. What could be the problem? How can I check or debug what could be causing this issue? Any solution or hints on this will be highly appreaciated.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load

Answer (score 0):

Inactive add-ins are usually caused by a missing reference that wasn't deployed. Try some of these resources:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haahmadi/archive/2010/05/26/my-vsto-add-in-does-not-load.aspx
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vstotroubleshooter