# Migrating Addin( with VSTO and .net 3.5) to .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, vsto, outlook-addin

I have my WPF application developed with .NET 3.5 framework and then I migrated it to the .NET 4.0 framework.
Linked to my app, I have also created an Addin for Outlook (2007 and 2010) with VSTO using .NET 3.5 framework (the Addin is enabled if my app is on).
Obviously my Addin with the client with .NET 4.0 framework doesn't work.
How can I upgrade my Addin with .NET 4.0 framework?

N.B. For the architecture of my app, I can't use clickonce.

Comment: Did you tried to troubleshoot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load

Comment: Yes, and thanks to this article that i've understood my problem. So my real goal now is more general: make an update to an Outlook addin. Any smart strategies?

Comment: What do you mean by update to an Outlook Addin?

Comment: I have to update my addin (also all the library) from .net 3.5 to .net 4.0 so as to communicate my addin with my client application (that was migrated to 4.0)

Comment: I believe it is straight forward by changing the framework in the property pages of the project.

Comment: Thanks kiru, i supposed that. in fact i've realized the brand new addin with 4.0. Now my question is: how can update over all the client machine this new version? Uninstalling the old and lanch the new setup? Is there a solution more flexible and automatic so as the final user just simply click one only button? Thanks in advice