# Create Word 2007 Add-in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, word-2007

I am creating Word 2007 add-in using visual studio 2010. I have searched a lot but i am confused now. Can somebody guide me below queries?

1) Can we develop word 2007 addin using visual studio 2010?
2) Can we develop Word 2007 addin only on machine having office 2007?
3) Do we need registry entries in HKLM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Can we develop word 2007 addin using visual studio 2010?`
- Yes

`Can we develop Word 2007 addin only on machine having office 2007?`
- No. You can develop add-in with [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28v=office.12%29.aspx) as well if you do not have Office 2007. 
- http://openxmldeveloper.org/

`Do we need registry entries in HKLM?`
- Yes, that will be done by Add-in itself, if needed.

A  good example -
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc442946%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Actually i have created word 2010 addin on machine having office 2010. As far as i found when we run the vsto file generated by build operation of office project it will be added for that particular user only. We want that admin should install it and it should be accessible for every user without requiring to install separately for every user with his login. I have created setup project for that purpose. It works perfectly for word 2010 and word 2013. It doesn't work for office 2007.

Comment: What happens with Office 2007?

Comment: It adds the Word addin in word 2007 but load behavior is Unloaded while registry entries added in HKLM shows load behavior Loaded. I have created addin 2007 as well on machine having office 2007 and when i deployed on another machine having office 2007 it doesn't load again while same setup works for office 2010 and office 2013.

Comment: Check if Office 2007 security settings are blocking your Add-in to be invoked.

Comment: How can we check security setting? what security is required? Actually when i run the Vsto file generated by build operation of office project.. the button is added successfully. it is not adding button when i run the setup file created by  me.

Comment: Here are the [instructions about security](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/help/enable-or-disable-add-ins-in-office-programs-HA010034127.aspx)

Comment: everything is fine as per the security setting.. I don't know exact cause of issue..

Comment: can you please suggest?

Comment: The description you provided is not enough for me to conclude anything about what is happening at your end. You can try troubleshooting it - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2008/04/22/troubleshooting-com-add-in-load-failures.aspx

Comment: How can we find the error log for add-ins not loading? If i can find error that will be really helpful.

Comment: Try to see if EventViewer has something interesting. Look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load

Comment: Do we need .Net framework 4.0 or 4.5 to make it working for word 2007? I have to install this on machine having office 2007. Does it matter what framework we used to create addin?

Comment: Yes. You need to have same framework on the target machine which you used build the addin. But your installer should complaint about it if it is not present on the target machine