# Available add-In VSTO

Tags: vsto, add-in

I build a setup project for vsto application (include projects for outlook, power point, excel and word)
when I'm installing the .msi file, it completed successfully , the keys of the Add-Ins are being added to the registry, but when I open Office application my button doesn't appear.

If I go to: Manage Com Add-Ins, under Add-ins available I find my add-in, but it is not checked as available Add-In.

What can I do to set the add-In as available by default ?

I Pay attention also that after I Open an Office application, the "LoadBehavior" key in the registry has changed to "2" instead of "3"...

please help....

Comment: Here is a bunch of things to check [How to troubleshoot VSTO Add-Ins that dont load](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14698249/495455). I think you have a problem in your code (that you'll need to debug) because Office tends to disable add-ins that produce errors. Welcome to [so] and good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I think I have another problem... I change the manifest key and Now when I open Office I got a popUp: "Publisher cannot be verified" if I choose "install" - it works good, but I don't want the users to get this popUp...

Comment: Hmm, weird. Are you installing from a network drive? http://superuser.com/questions/341091/how-to-get-rid-of-the-publisher-cannot-be-verified-on-network-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks For trying to help :)

Finally, I found it...

The problem was because I Have more than one vsto projects to Install.

So, First of all I sign every Add-In project with Strong Key, 
Then, In the Setup Project -> Right Click on View -> Custom actions
Under "Insatll" Folder, I add the primary output of my Add-In projects.

The problem was solved.