# Cannot debug excel vsto add-in. Excel opens and closes immediately

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto, vba

I am trying to create an excel add-in using Visual Studio 2013. The add-in is for Excel 2010.

Now the issue I am facing...
I am not able to run the add-in in debug mode.
When I click "Start" to debug my code, Excel opens and closes immediately. This issue does not have anything to do with my project, because the issue happens even when I create a fresh add-in project without any code.

The following message is displayed in the output window.

```
'excel.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[10116] excel.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[10116] excel.exe' has exited with code -2146233082 (0x80131506).
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever get this fixed Ian?

Comment: No, I am yet to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening Excel first instead of using 'Start' to debug, then from your Visual Studio solution click on the Debug menu > 'Attach to Process' and select EXCEL.EXE from the list of available processes.

This works for me as I also have the Office app quit on me when using 'Start'

Answer (score 1):

**Symptom:**
In Visual Studio, Debugging (F5) a VSTO Add-In launches Excel and then the Excel process crashes.

**Solution:**
Create an XML file called Excel.Exe.Config:

```
<configuration>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v1.1.4322"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v1.0.3705"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

The versions must match what you find in C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework.

Place Excel.Exe.Config in the folder that contains Excel.exe,
eg:C:\program files\Microsoft Office\Office14

If using .Net 2 resolves the problem you can narrow it down to .Net 4.5 by seeing if .Net 4 will work, eg:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
```

---

If the above doesn't work please [enable VSTO logging as I discuss here (#7)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14698249/495455) and [is detailed in depth here](http://www.macroview.com.au/support/KnowledgeBase/Pages/20110084.aspx) and add those details to your question.

---

**Edit:**

1. I have this vague memory of something similar happening to me, *I should have documented it* - make sure the Office VSTO Runtime installed on the PC?
2. You don't have multiple versions of Office installed do you? That is not supported as per: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2007/06/08/why-is-vs-development-not-supported-with-multiple-versions-of-office.aspx
3. Try it on another PC? Does it work - if so its PC specific and you should do a repair &/or uninstall/reinstall of Office and Visual Studio
4. Make sure you can debug other applications like winform app? And you can debug a Word or Outlook Add-In?
5. It's a long shot (and I understand its Visio not Excel) but is EMET installed: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c259df5b-d76c-4de4-86c9-6690522cd9b8/visio-crashes-when-debugging-addin-in-visual-studio?forum=vsto
6. If the above fail more in depth troubleshooting is required. Setup [Adplus](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350) to take a Crash *using the -pn switch set to Excel*. Reproduce the problem then open the Memory Dump in windbg and issue a !analyze command.

Comment: Tried it, but did not work. In addition VSTO logging also doesn't work for me. Added the environment variables, no messages shown and cannot find the file .manifest.log

Comment: No VSTO messages logged? Hmm thats weird. a) Please double check [you have it setup correctly](http://www.macroview.com.au/support/KnowledgeBase/Pages/20110084.aspx), b) Hook up these two events: System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, c) You are running Visual Studio as an Admin right? and d) Does it work if you start Excel and then attach a debugger to the Excel process?

Comment: a. Yes, I did it correctly. b. Not sure how to do it. c. Yes. d. No

Comment: 1. VSTO Runtime is installed. 2. I have only Office 2010 installed. 3. Issue is present on all machines at my office. 4. I can debug other applications like winform but not addins. Same issue for Outlook and Word. 5. EMET is not installed. 6. Will try.

Comment: Any luck? or any closer to the last resort (memory dump)?

Answer (score -2):

Check the project target framework may be project is targeting .Net framework 4.5 try changing target framework to .Net framework 4

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/14a645f3-4ecd-4815-9fdd-eb2756b70945/net-45-office-2010-addin