# VSTO Microsoft Office Outlook 2013 Addins keep disabling Ribbon

Tags: c#, outlook

I developed an application using C# Outlook ribbon Addins. Its working fine, but its keep disabling when outlook start.

Comment: Check this SO thread regarding VSTO addin troubleshooting: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load)

Comment: i tried the link which mentioned in the comment, but its still happening with Microsoft Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your add-in listed in the Disabled Items list?

Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the [Startup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.addin.startup.aspx) event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the [Startup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.addin.startup.aspx) event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again.

See [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Also Outlook 2013 monitors add-in performance metrics such as add-in startup, shutdown, folder switch, item open, and invoke frequency. Outlook records the elapsed time in milliseconds for each performance monitoring metric.
For example, the startup metric measures the time required by each connected add-in during Outlook startup. Outlook then computes the median startup time over 5 successive iterations. If the median startup time exceeds 1000 milliseconds (1 second), then Outlook disables the add-in and displays a notification to the user that an add-in has been disabled. The user has the option of always enabling the add-in, in which case Outlook will not disable the add-in even if the add-in exceeds the 1000 millisecond performance threshold. See [Performance criteria for keeping add-ins enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679.aspx#ol15WhatsNew_AddinDisabling).

Comment: I used to enable this Addins only when they click for New Email, and its only shows compose window ribbon. I used the following method Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose, Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read

Comment: Do you get any UI errors in Outlook? See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: No, Its working perfect with out any other issue, only get disabled from Outlook 2013

Comment: Is it disabled in Outlook 2013? Am I right? If so, do you get any exceptions in the code?

Comment: Yes, its always get disabled. Every time i enable from the Option - > Add-Ins - Inactive Application Add-Ins and check for get enabled.

Comment: It looks the code fires exceptions. See my reply above for more information.