# Word Addin not working in 64bit office but working on 32bit office

Tags: c#, wix, vsto, office-addins

I have developed an addin for Microsoft word and its working perfectly on 32 bit of office applications.  Unfortunately I found that an installer for 64-bit Windows requires two registry paths because it’s possible for users to run 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Office on a computer that runs 64-bit Windows

On a 64 bit of windows:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE(32-Bit)\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\SampleCompany.WordAddIn
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE(64-Bit)\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\SampleCompany.WordAddIn
```

I have developed a setup using Wix Installer, ut for me 32 bit works perfectly and for 64 bit my addin was not not loaded and I [troubleshooted using this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load/14698249#14698249).  Atlast I found that my Addin was loaded under `InActive Application Add-Ins` in Microsoft word. I tried enabling it, thought it was not getting enabled and still remains in the same place!

What was the problem..?

My WIX project TargetPlatform was **x86.**

Comment: What is the target platform of your Add-In?

Comment: @bradfordrg both the platforms.(64 and 32 )

Comment: You haven't really said exactly what you're doing, but for the 64-bit system you need a 64-bit MSI with two identical components with that key etc, except that one will be Win64="yes" assuming that you want to deal with both 32-bit and 64-bit clients on a 64-bit system.  You can't target the 64-bit key from a 32-bit install.