# VSTO Word 2010 AddIn not visible in Ribbon after clickonce install

Tags: visual-studio, ms-word, vsto

I got an Word AddIn (VS2012,.Net4, Word 2010, Word 2013) which is deployed via ClickOnce - works fine. After installation the AddIn is shown as active in the options, but it is not visible in the ribbon. Why is it invisble?

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load, especially the VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS is pretty helpful

Comment: Hi, the AddIn is not disabled! It is only invisible on the menu. In the options it is shown as active and loaded!

Comment: Possibly the Ribbon code is running into a problem. Is "Show user interface errors" activated on the target machine in File/Options/Advanced/General? When it is, any errors generated by the Ribbon will be shown to the user, which might provide a clue as to the problem.

Comment: Cindy thank you. I got an unknown office control id error.