# Outlook Addin starts up inactive

Tags: outlook, add-in, outlook-addin

This is a very strange situation that I am in; scratching my head for answers.

I have developed an outlook addin that works perfectly on my dev machine and on about 90 % of the clients machines.

The load behavior of the addin is 3.

On 10% of the users, outlook starts up without loading the addin despite the load behaviour being 3. The user can manually make the addin active by going to the addin manager on outlook but after a restart this addin reverts back to being inactive bbut load behavior never changes from 3.

I used Install Shield LE to package this addin. I don't even know where to debug anymore, I tried changing different load behaviour values but still the same outcome. The addin just won't load on startup with this set of users.

The company uses ZenWorks to automatically install the addin on all the PCs from the MSI i generate using install shield.

One weird thing is, If i go to the installation directory of the addin and install the addin using the .vsto deployment file, it works and gets loaded on outlook (but thats makes it two addins installed).

I also checked the Resiliency section on the registry and the addin isn't there.

Comment: It sometime happens, if you have the chance, try to reinstall office on one of the problematic machine. It can also be caused by some other add-ins (I also saw corrupted .NetFramework). Occasionally we had to reinstall Windows. Also try to switch on the [VSTO suppress errors and others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load)

Comment: @PetLahev Thanks, now i have two more debugging options on my list (reinstall + possibly try reinstalling dot net) I will be on the client site to try this. I hope they can give me the right of reinstalling office. I already told them to switch on  VSTO suppress errors but there were no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced this issue. To solve this, you need to manually delete the registry entries from the following path.

Open registry editor and go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\<Your add-in>` and change the LoadBehavior to 3.

If the above registry entry is not found, then look for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\<Your add-in>` and change the LoadBehavior to 3.

Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Resiliency` – remove the `REG_BINARY` keys found in `DisabledItems` and `CrashingAddinList` 
  where 15.0 is for outlook 2013.
If you are using 2010 outlook, replace 15.0 by 14.0 and for Outlook 2016 replace 15.0 by 16.0

Hope this helps.