# Outlook 2013 Add-in Installation Issues

Tags: c#, outlook, installation, add-in, installshield-le

I developed an Outlook 2013 Add-in using VS2015 (C#).

On Friday I built an installer (InstallShield Limited Edition Project - SingleImage) for it and ran it on my machine. Installation went perfectly and the add-in was running kind of smoothly (few functionalities weren't working).

Today I started working on it again, changed some things and rebuilt my installer to see if I could fix those buggy functionalities. I uninstalled the previous version of the add-in via the Control Panel and ran the newest setup.exe.

Upon running Outlook I realized my add-in had not been installed (I have a message pop up on start to check if the add-in was installed correctly). I started messing around on Outlook and found the add-in listed as inactive.

Checked it off as active and got an error message about not finding some files or whatever. Deleted it from the list, uninstalled the add-in, restarted the machine and tried it all again with no progress.

If I try to add the .dll or .vsto files manually to the Add-in list I get a "file not a valid Outlook add-in" error message. Even running the original setup.exe gets me the same error messages.

Why on earth is this happening? Was I not supposed to manually delete the add-in from Outlook's list? Should I reinstall Outlook?

Comment: P.S.: Just ran Outlook on another machine and the add-in ran on it even though I never installed it. Outlook automatically found the .vsto file in my debug/Release project folder. WTF?!

Comment: Just a guess, I think that the uninstallation process was not working correctly and you somehow broke it. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load) and let us know