# Outlook addin doesn't load and also doesn't show as disable or inactive, even though correct registry was created

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I have created an outlook VSTO Addin using visual studio 2012, .net framework 4.5 . It loads correctly,on various machine that I have tested. But on two client machines it is not loading, even though correct registry entry has been created under path.

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\

Also, the plugin is installed correctly, it shows up in the Add or remove programs.But the addin is not visible even in the inactive or disable list in outlook.The load behavior is still 3 in the registry.So, what could be the cause of the issue?

Comment: Is it shown in File | Options | Addins?

Comment: No, it doesn't show it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice post on msdn to learn how to debug VSTO addins : see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brijs/2008/10/10/tips-and-tricks-for-troubleshooting-office-add-ins-part-1/).

Essentially you can display loading-time error message for your add-in by setting the environment variable (on your customer machine) `VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS` to 0. For an example see [here](http://blog.bananatag.com/knowledgebase/how-do-i-enable-vsto-errordisplay-alerts/) .

See also this  post : [How to troubleshoot a VSTO addin that does not load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load)