# Office Addin 2016 Doesn't work on all machines

Tags: ms-office, vsto, add-in

I am new here for this Topic, developing Office Add in 2016 it is working on my machine it doesn't work on any other machine using msi file. i have no idea why?
i need help in this i tried everything and don't know why it is not working on other machines.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons why your add-ins can be disabled. I'd suggest starting from checking the required prerequisites and making sure no exceptions are thrown in the code. Is your add-in listed in the Disabled Items list?

See [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) for more information.

Also make sure the required windows registry keys were added properly at the installation time. See [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106(v=vs.90).aspx).

The following article describe all the required steps for creating an MSI installer:

- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx)

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot for your reply
I can't find it in disabled Add In !!
about Registry i saved in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Office/16.0/Addin_Name

Comment: Do you see your add-in listed in the COM add-ins list in Office?

Comment: It is not displayed !!

Comment: Then you didn't create the required windows registry keys.

Comment: I did in that way hkey_local_machinr/Software/Microsoft/office/16.0/Addin_Name please tell me if it's ok?

Comment: See [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was caused by Antivirus it blocked the installed add in.