# Word Addin application not displayed in the Word ribbon

Tags: vsto, registrykey, word-addins

I made a Word add in application in VS 2010 in C# and it was working fine until I installed the app using Advanced Installer in my development PC and its doesn't display anymore in the Word ribbon. I check the registry files and it looks fine, tried to add the same registry keys in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER and the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE directories in the registry Editor window but still no effect.

I even create another add in as a test and it wasn't displayed in the word ribbon.

When I check the Addin options in the Word option window the addin is located in the Active Application Addin which indicates that addin is loaded and working but still can't be displayed in the word ribbon.

I also tried to re-install the whole office package and restore the PC configuration to the date before installing the app but still nothing works.

The registry keys I use for the Addin are listed below:

```
Description: My_Addin
FriendlyName: My_Addin
LoadBehavior: 3 (DWORD (32-bit) value)
Manifest: file:///C:/Application folder/My_Addin.vsto|vstolocal
```

Comment: If you go to File/Options/Add-ins then look at the bottom of that dialog box you should see a dropdown list. Select COM Add-ins then click "Go". Is your add-in listed there? Is the checkbox next to it activated, or not? What's the "Load behavior" (bottom of the dialog box) If you don't find it here, go back to the Add-ins list and from the same dropdown box choose "Disabled items" - is it listed here?

Comment: it is listed in the COM Add-ins window and checked. the loading behavior is loading at startup

Comment: Are you able to debug it? So the Startup method is called? Also try to add VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS and try the other steps mentioned here, especially make sure the add-in is not disabled - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load

Comment: Also check in Word: File/Options/Advanced/General the option "Show add-in user interface errors". That needs to be activated in order to see whether the Ribbon code is erroring.