# Microsoft word add in error VSTO

Tags: ms-word, vsto, windows-7-x64

We have a Microsoft word add-in that is working fine on the majority of pc's.

On a particular windows 7 pc, it has the  visual studio 2010 tools for office installed correctly.

But when a user creates a new template word document, they get teh following error:

> The customization assembly could not be found or could not be loaded.
>   You can still edit and save the document. Contact your administrator
>   or the author of this document for further assistance.

We have tried unloading all dependencies but still does not make any difference.

This is an issue effecting a small amount of windows 7 pc's with office 2016 installed. It seems to be pc related rather than the application.

Comment: One of these may help: [Troubleshooting Office Solution Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608594.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the reason behind such an error is that the permissions for loading the VSTO solution are missing. One thing that often gets "missed" when deploying VSTO solutions is that the document must be in a "trusted location". You might want to check that this is the case by looking in the Word "Trust Center" (in the Options). You also need to be sure you've installed the correct version of the VSTO run-time for the version of Windows and Office. Read more about that in the [Troubleshooting Run Time Errors in Office Solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/6s0wczt9(v=vs.100)) article.

Also it may indicate that you didn't include all required dependencies to your add-in's installer (any platform-specific assemblies). Something is missing on the target machines, so I'd suggest looking for any difference between machines. You can add the .NET Framework, the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime, and the Office primary interop assemblies to your Setup package as prerequisites that are deployed with your Office solution. For information about how to install the primary interop assemblies, see [Configuring a Computer to Develop Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242.aspx) and [How to: Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx).

The required steps for deploying Office solutions are described in the following articles:

- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You can use the event viewer in Windows to see error messages that are captured by the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime when you install or uninstall Office solutions. You can use these messages from the event logger to resolve installation and deployment problems. For more information, see [Event Logging for Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442816.aspx).

See [Troubleshooting Office Solution Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608594.aspx) for more information.