# System.NullReferenceException at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase.Dispose(Boolean)

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

I created my first Excel VSTO Add-in. Everything is working great in Visual Studio. I published my Add-in, installed on other computer but Excel has crashed during loading. Only not responding dialog was shown.

- I was trying to create add-in for 2013 and newer versions
- I set `VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS` to 0 --> No alert shown
- I tried to set `VSTO_LOGALERTS` to 1 --> No log
- I checked register manifest value, path is correct
- I tried to modify manifest value to wrong one --> Log was written with information about file not found
- So I know that `VSTO_LOGALERTS` works but not for my case
- I also checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load)
- Only information which I found in event log was:

> Application: EXCEL.EXE
>       Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>       Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>       Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
>          at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase.Dispose(Boolean)
>          at ExcelTE.RibbonTE.Dispose(Boolean)
>          at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize()

In prerequisites I have checked these options:

[image: prerequisites]

I also tried to install .NET framework 4.7.2 and Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime manually but without success.

Any ideas what else I can check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I don't think so..  My code is working fine when debugging, problem is when Add-In is published..

Comment: Is ExcelTE your add-in? Does this happen on your dev machine when published? If so, you can attach Visual Studio's debugger and step through it to see exactly when this happens.

Comment: Yes ExcelTE is the name of my Add-In. Unfortunately on my dev machine everything working. Even when I try to install this add-in, so I can't use your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this problem.

The `System.NullReferenceException` was little bit misleading for this.

I created a project, then added:

- Ribbon
- On ribbon I've added button
- For button I've created click event handler

I had my custom logic in event handler.It was using 3rd party library. This library requires to have Resources/someSettingsFile.settings folder in user Documents.

I was doing initialization of object from 3rd party library when MyRibbon class was created. So this throws exception during loading excel.

I forgot that I copied Resources folder to Documents during development and when I published Add-In to other users they simply doesn't have files required by 3rd library.