# Work on same Visual Studio project from 2 computers

Tags: visual-studio, vsto, office-addins, ribbonx

I have a VSTO project, with a custom ribbon for Excel and some forms, and I have the following problem: I'm trying to work on the same project on both a PC and on a laptop for mobility (started on PC).

I synchronized the project folder with Dropbox, I installed the certificate on my laptop.
On the PC, no problems. On the laptop, I don't get any errors but when I run it, it does not display the custom ribbon.
Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can use Microsoft Azure DevOps Services for source control for free when the team members are 5 or less. https://dev.azure.com/

Comment: I’ve been doing this for years with onedrive, google drive and now synology with a Word vsto.  I do not recognize this situation but have you checked that that the vsto com addin is loaded? And what happens if you compile and run from your IDE? (Visual studio assumed)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure the add-in is loaded by the host application. Try to set a breakpoint and start debugging from VS. If any breakpoint is hit then you need to start working on the ribbon errors. If not, you need to check why the add-in is not loaded by the host application. There are multiple reasons why the add-in may not be loaded, see [How to troubleshoot a VSTO addin that does not load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load) for more information.

By default, if a VSTO add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear.

To show VSTO Add-in user interface errors you need:

1. Start the application.
2. Click the `File` tab.
3. Click `Options`.
4. In the categories pane, click `Advanced`.
5. In the details pane, select `Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors`, and then click `OK`.

See [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2022) for more information.