# Convert PDF to Image in web application

Tags: c#, pdf, web-applications, nullreferenceexception

How can I convert a PDF into an image in web application?

I am following this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57100/Simple-and-Free-PDF-to-Image-Conversion) to convert; it is working fine in window applications but in web applications, on,

```
Clipboard.GetImage().Save(outimg, outPutImageFormat);
```

It's throwing this exception,

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How I can implement this in Web Application?

Comment: Did you try looking up the exception? Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution :

1.)https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/ ( a wrapper for the Ghostscript library )

2.) https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Ghostscript.NET/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/DeviceUsageSample.cs GhostscriptDevice usage sample

3.)https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Ghostscript.NET/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/ProcessorSample.cs Also see this one.

Comment: Although open source, it is not free for commercial use. are there any free alternatives?

Comment: I think it is free and i am using it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this :

[LibPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831742/convert-pdf-to-image-without-using-ghostscript-dll) library converts converts PDF file to an image. Supported image formats are PNG and BMP, but you can easily add more.

Comment: Did you implemented this in web ?

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't support x64 though