# Selecting specific region from image

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, pdftotext

Is there any .net free library for winform or wpf which can provide control to select specifics regions in an image and then we can save that regions as different images. It will be great if we can draw a grid using mouse on an image and then save that grid as separate image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PDF to Image without using Ghostscript DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831742/convert-pdf-to-image-without-using-ghostscript-dll)

Comment: Have you looked into [JCrop](http://jcrop.org/)?

Comment: its window form /wpf web or what?? must specify. that actually really required to understand what exactly you want

Comment: I want a tool for windows application. It can be WPF or Winform control. It can select region in an image and can save that region. That region should be movable and resizable also we can draw as many regions. Is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very hard. In Winforms here is a minimal example:

```
GraphicsPath GP = null;
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    points.Clear();
    points.Add(e.Location);
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    GP = new GraphicsPath();
    GP.AddClosedCurve(points.ToArray());
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        points.Add(e.Location);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (points.Count > 1)
        e.Graphics.DrawCurve(Pens.Orange, points.ToArray(), 0.5f);
}

private void cb_clearRegion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    points.Clear();
    pictureBox1.Region = null;
}

private void cb_SaveRegion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle cr = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle;
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(cr.Width, cr.Height))
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        G.SetClip(GP);
        G.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, Point.Empty);
        bmp.Save(@"D:\xyz.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't use zooming in or out and creates bitmap that all have the same size as the original, just transparent everywhere outside the region.

Implementing  azoom is trivial, using `ScaleTransform` and a `Point UnZoom(Point)` function; just ask if you need it..

If you want to add a 'move' mode you can use the `MouseMove` and re-calculate all the `Points`.

If you want several regions you will have to collect a `List<T>` and use them successively to create the output.

If you really want only the grid saved, without the image, use `G.DrawPath(..)` instead of `DrawImage()` !

Also note that you may want to use various drawing tools like lines, rectanlges etc to refine the selection. You can incrementally add figures to the path..