# C# application .Net 2.0 Couldn't run in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, c#-2.0, .net-assembly

I built a .Net 2.0 Application for Windows XP but I made it in Windows 7.

The application contains a Mysql.data connection and CrystalReport. When I try to run it on Windows XP, the application does not run, giving an error message of:

> The application failed to initialize properly (0xc000007b).

I tried to rebuild application in Windows XP, but when I rebuilt and ran it in Visual Studio, the following error occurs:

> Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Refer [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

1.Uninstall the .NET Framework 3.5 from Add/Remove Programs (in the Control Panel) on Windows XP or Programs and Features on Windows Vista/Windows 7.

Even if the uninstall fails, go on to step 2.

2.After the Framework 3.5 has been uninstalled or if it failed, download and run the .NET Framework removal tool.

Here's the link to Aaron Stebner's Framework Removal tool on Windows Live Skydrive:

http://cid-27e6a35d1a492af7.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Blog_Tools/dotnetfx_cleanup_tool.zip?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=17797669

Aaron Stebner is a Microsoft employee. The tool he's developed is linked on that page and makes easy work of cleaning up damaged .NET Frameworks from your system so they can be reinstalled. When you run the tool, choose the .NET Framework 3.5 from the list and choose to cleanup. After this is done, reinstall the .NET Framework 3.5 that Design 3 needs by running the Expression Design 3 setup package again. It will detect that the .NET Framework 3.5 is missing and reinstall it for you. After that's done, try running Design 3 again.

3.If that still fails to resolve the problem, go to START, RUN and type CMD to run a command prompt. Type CHKDSK /R and hit ENTER. Hit the letter Y and restart the machine. Allow the machine to do the check disk scan. After this is done and it goes back into Windows, try Expression Design again. 
 more information [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/2b348d1e-ed0a-4ef0-8957-fcb827b8972c/the-application-failed-to-initialize-properly-0xc000007b-click-on-ok-to-terminate-the-application)

Comment: I have try all parts of your answer but still error with the same message.

Comment: @IsaHariman Did you try this?  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/2b348d1e-ed0a-4ef0-8957-fcb827b8972c/the-application-failed-to-initialize-properly-0xc000007b-click-on-ok-to-terminate-the-application