# .NET Core 2.0 dependency issue

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I have a library used in various project and made with .net core 2.0; the library is called 'Coconut'; the test is done on Windows.

When I try to build a simple test project to test some functionalities, the test code will not run.

The test is very simple:

[image]

but when I run it:

[image]

And the output is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Coconut, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

and the console shows the same problem:

[image]

What I don't understand is that the DLL that is not found is built in the same solution and everything was built through Visual Studio's tooling.

We can clearly see the dll in the same folder.

Edit:

When checking with procmon, there is not a single operation trying to load 'coconut.dll'; that string is completely absent from the log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742777/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Comment: Not a duplicate since the issue here is specific to .net core 2.0, since I don't have any similar problem with 4.x; furthermore the solution proposed is nothing more than an invitation to dig more through the problem.

Comment: That being said. I did check the filesystem operations with procmon and I edited the post