# Missing dll when using web services with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, service

I have a solution with several projects in it, one of them being a website. The website has references to five web services, which are being run on our own servers. When building the website with VS 2010 I get the following error:

> Validating Web Site
>   App_WebReferences/VpService/(1): Build (web): Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly "Konzeptum.BL.Base, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" or one of it's dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.

The service that produces this error changes on every build. The apparently missing dll cannot be found on any of the machines I looked at, it's not even present on the servers running the services. The services however have references to some APIs which in turn have references to the dlls *Konzeptum.BL.Telerate.Provisioning, Konzeptum.VO.Base, Konzeptum.VO.Telerate.Provisioning*. My *guess* is that these dlls make use of the missing *Konzeptum.BL.Base*.

I can compile each project just fine (the services, APIs etc.) just the website has this problem. I have tried updating the service references, deleting and re-adding them, nothing. The only solution I could find online (and that kind of works) is deactivating the reuse of types in the *Service Reference Settings* for each service. I uncheck the three dlls mentioned above and reuse all other types.

Now however if I build the website I get errors that there are ambiguous references between types provided by the service and existing ones (e.g. FileInfo from System.IO) or errors that some data types cannot be found. These missing types however have nothing to do with *Konzeptum* stuff, they are defined by the services themselves. Luckily for me these errors pop up very late in the build process of the website, so that most of it is usable.

What could be the cause of these problems and how can I solve them?
Thank you for any help.

**Edit:**
Maybe it wasn't clear before, but this problem seems to occur only on my machine, two other developers don't have any problems building the website (and we're using the same tfs repository). The servers running the live system don't have any problems. But the missing dll is not present anywhere, so I can't just copy it over. The Assembly Binding Log Viewer isn't of much help either, in the entry for *Konzeptum.BL.Base* under Calling assembly it just says (Unknown).

Comment: this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. The Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fuslogvw.exe) shows entries for the missing Konzeptum.BL.Base, but exept a bunch of paths doesn't seem to provide much information. On every entry under Calling assembly it says (Unknown).

Comment: you have it referenced correct? If so can't you just change property of copy to local to true?

Comment: The references of the APIs that use the three Konzeptum dlls are correct. Copy local is set to true on all of them. I verified that these three dlls get copied to Website\Bin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after searching for differences between my machine and those of the other developers I found one that I thought shouldn't matter at all. They had .NET version 4.0 installed vs. version 4.5.1 on my PC. So after uninstalling 4.5.1 and installing 4.0 the problem went away. I can now successfully compile the whole solution without any errors. Why that is - I have no idea. The projects in the solution all target 4.0, so I thought running them under 4.5.1 should be no problem, but I guess not. I even went through the list of changes between [4.0 and 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/hh367887%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/[4.5.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dn458352%28v=vs.110%29), but I couldn't find anything that relates to my problem.

Thanks to anyone that tried to help.