# Could not load file or assembly, confused

Tags: c#

I've been occasionally getting this popup stopping me from saving/building my project, can anybody advise me on how best to debug this? I'm only able to find information on Google related to referencing my own DLLs, which i'm not. I have a feeling it has something to do with either a custom control or a couple of simple control extensions that i have in my project. What's more confusing is that it seems to randomly occur :S

[image: Could not load file or assembly]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4469929/1997232) for hints.

Comment: I had already followed that post to no avail, thanks though.

Comment: Does it occur regularly if you do a clean before the build? Is AuctionX one of the solution projects or a third party assembly?

Comment: I don't think so Nanhydrin, while i do have a habit of cleaning the build occasionally, i'm pretty sure i just hit rebuild prior to it happening this time, and AuctionX is the main project.

Comment: I think if i delete my custom control/extended controls from my form it will allow me to build again, of course i don't want to keep having to do this, so i really need to find the root cause.

Comment: AuctionX is the main and only project in the solution, and i have added no other dependencies, hence this error makes no sense to me.

Comment: Are the custom user controls in the same project?

Comment: Yes, i have one user control in the same project.