# Could not load file or assembly '"Rancho's POS System"' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#

[image: could not load...]

does anyone know the cause and how to solve it?

I have big problems in this because the system I'm doing won't run properly because I can't make any debug in this

Comment: Have you added a reference to the DLL?

Comment: Hopefully this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Comment: how to do that? and where do I find that .dll?