# PowerShell script is throwing an error Type Initiliazer

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am having one C# code which is working fine. I made PS script of same functionality which is not working.

```
$config = New-Object MyClass
```

Error it is throwing is

> Type initializer for MyClass2 threw an exception.

Type initializer error is coming from other class(MyClass2) object which is strange.

I checked inner exception that says

> Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.

But all of assemblies are loaded.

P.S. - I made a console application in .net and tried to make MyClass object with all same assemblies which i used in PS script. In this application works perfectly fine.

P.S. - Same PS script is working in VS2015, if i make PS project and run script through VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

First, determine which assembly is missing, (for example using Dependency Walker, see [this answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37483971/1163423)). Then add the missing assembly using the `Add-Type` cmdlet:

```
Add-Type -Path "path_to_your_assembly"
```

Comment: Actually I have loaded all the assemblies for safe side but still it is throwing same error. But same PS script is working in VS2015, so i guess its not related to any assembly.