# Affdex .NET SDK - Could not load file or assembly Affdex or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, wpf, affdex-sdk

I'm having error when running WPF application with reference to `C:\Program Files\Affectiva\Affdex SDK\bin\release\Affdex.dll`

Exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Affdex, Version=3.1.1.419, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."
```

The WPF application is running under .Net Framework 4.5 and I'm running SDK version downloaded as `AffdexSDK-3.1.1-419-win64.exe`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

According [to this](http://developer.affectiva.com/v3_1_1/windows/) `Affdex.dll` depends on `affdex-native.dll` and loads it in runtime. Make sure that the latter is accessible to your program by adding it to your `%PATH%` variable or by adding it to your visual studio project. See example in [AffdexMe](https://github.com/Affectiva/affdexme-win) source code.