# could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.MVC, version 4.0.0.0,'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, runtime-error

I am getting run time error from one of the projects which is not an MVC project. I recently upgraded .net framework from 4.0 to 4.5.2 and am building the solution for deployment using MS Build 12.0. The solution builds just fine but am seeing the above exception when I run the service which has no reference to the said assembly.

The project is run as a windows service which uses windows workflow foundation to run some rules. I don't have IIS enabled on the target server and the web related dlls haven't been deployed as well

Comment: care to post your web.config file and a dir listing of the BIN folder where your app is built to?

Comment: There is no configuration file for the project in which I am getting this run time error, also MVC reference isn't added into any project that is deployed into this web server

Comment: There's no config file at all, not even a default one on the target server's iis (a machine config) ? It shouldn't even get as far as this error message then.. I suspect there IS a config file somewhere, and it's calling for that DLL to be loaded, but it's not being found.. when you say "when I run the service" - how are you running this service? What version of IIS? And is it on your machine or elsewhere?

Comment: my bad, I haven't mentioned many details, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check Windows service assemblies by this tool to understand what assembly requires MVC:
[Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies/44251000#44251000)