# Azure functions failing when upgrading to 1.0.8

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Using the latest version of VS 2017 I

- Create a new azure functions project.
- Add a timer trigger function
- Upgrade to latest (1.0.8) azure functions nuget package
- Add a reference to azure storage for creating table client
- run the project, and it just failes on load.

> A ScriptHost error has occurred [06.03.2018 20.46.05] Exception while
>   executing function: Function1. FunctionApp2: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.6.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not find or
>   load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621).
>   System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.6.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Sample code:

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("[someConnectionString]");
        var tbc = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage

According to your error message , it seems that you have missed the **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage** assembly or the package version conflict. You could check whether you have used the same package of different versions. Check the  compatibility of dependencies of [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions) . Or try to uninstall then reinstall the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions  package.

I follow your steps to install  **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions** 1.0.8 from **Manage Nuget Packages** in Visual Studio. Then I run the TimeTrigger directly. Everything works fine. I could see the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage package in dependencies.

[image]

And you could check the  **project.assets** file in your Azure function folder.

[image]

The running result:

[image]

Besides, this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies) have some similar issues, you could refer to.