# Could not load file or assembly Ghostscript.NET

Tags: c#, ghostscript, rasterize, ghostscript.net

I am using Ghostscript.Net, Version=1.2.1.0,  to rasterize PDF to images. I have referenced both the 32 bit-gsdll32.dll and 64 bit-gsdll64.dll of ghostscript in my project directory/bin folder. I am using this piece of code to get the path of the ghostscript dll:

```
var ghostScriptPath = Environment.Is64BitProcess ? HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/bin/gsdll64.dll"):
                HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/bin/gsdll32.dll");
```

This works fine on local end, I don't have any issues rasterizing the PDF, however after being deployed to server, it throws exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Ghostscript.NET, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f85051de34525b59' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>    File name: 'Ghostscript.NET, Version=1.2.1.0

Any idea on how to tackle the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate  [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4469929/7517846)

Comment: Added the question after spending an hour or two searching for a possible answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: might be better to just delete this question

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out what I was missing. The exception itself is self explanatory,
I included the native ones ( gsdll32.dll / gsdll64.dll ) but missed to include the managed dll ( Ghostscript.NET.dll ) and thus the exception. I added the Ghostscript.Net.dll file to the bin directory of my project and this solved the issue. My bad, I should have been more careful.

Thanks.