# Unable to load custom visualizer of LLBL Gen Pro in VS19

Tags: c#, visual-studio, llblgenpro, llblgen

I am using Visual Studio 2019. 
To *C:\Users...\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Visualizers* I have added the following dll files to enable a visualizer for predicate buckets by LLBL Gen Pro. This approach works for VS 2017.

The dll files: `SD.LLBLGen.Pro.DebugVisualizers2017.dll, SD.LLBLGen.Pro.DQE.SqlServer.dll, SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.dll`

When trying to use it in VS19, I get the following error prompt:

> Unable to load the custom visualizer. Could not load file or assembly
>   'SD.LLBLGen.Pro.DebugVisualizers2017, Version=5.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ca73b74ba4e3ff27' or one of its
>   dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131515)

Has anyone encountered this problem before? What could I do about it?

The code snippet where I am trying to observe/ visualize the predicate:

```
     class Something {

     public void DoSG(TransactionListFilters filters)  
     {

          var transactionBucket = GetTransactionBucket(filters);
          var locationBucket = GetTransactionBucket(filters, false, true); }

          ...
     }
```

Comment: I guess, that `DebugVisualizers2017` means version for VS 2017. You'll need a version for VS 2019

Comment: The error message says "or one of its dependencies". `DebugVisualizers2017.dll` most likely depends on a specific version of some Visual Studio dll and can't load without it. It's no different than a `Could not load file or assembly` error for any application. The way to solve it is to add a binding redirect in the application's app.config (in this case Visual Studio's) that points to the new version.

Comment: Check this possibly duplicate question [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

The debugger visualizers are compiled against the visualizer dll for the particular vs version. For vs 2019 we ship a visualizer in v5.6 which is currently in beta.

ps: next time, ask the question on our support forums as we don't actively monitor stack overflow. https://www.llblgen.com/tinyforum.

If you want to have the visualizer be compiled against the dll from vs 2019, use the sourcecode for the runtimes, which is available to you on our website after you've logged in (under the extras section for downloads for a particular version).