# Why are there 2 different versions in System.IO.FileLoadException :Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, file, io, .net-assembly, fileloadexception

When I get a `System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly` there are always 2 different Versions in the error message.

But the error text for both is the same:

> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=**4.0.2.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

...and:

> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=**4.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

It says that version **`4.0.2.0`** could not be loaded and it says also that version **`4.0.0.0`** could not be loaded.

What are these 2 versions exactly mean and which is the real version who could not be found?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Comment: No, I asked what is the difference between these versions.

Comment: Consider the scenario where I am using Newtonsoft.Json in my project. I am also referencing some library that is also using Newtonsoft.Json but with different version. Those are the two versions Shows in the log.

Comment: I know this scenario: you have a web application targeting .NET Framework 4.6+, you have a NuGet package targeting .NET Standard, and you only get this error after deploying to the web server. Am I right?

Comment: @CodeCaster I only get this error on the build server if I run the system test project. On my local machine, all is working fine. The system test starts a .NET 4.6.1 project which hosts an asp.net core 2.0 web API project.

Comment: Yeah so that's a dependency hell introduced by the .NET Standard facade assemblies. I think installing .NET Core on the build server fixed it, but try searching for this error and now you'll know what to look for.