# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ML.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, ml.net

I have the following code:

```
[Command("aitest2")]
public async Task test(string text)
{
    var input = new ModelInput();
    input.SentimentText = text;
    // Load model and predict output of sample data
    ModelOutput result = ConsumeModel.Predict(input);
    await ReplyAsync($"Text: {input.SentimentText}\nIs Toxic: {result.Prediction}");
}
```

It gives me the error:
 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ML.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
Upon searching this up I have gotten no results/answers
I am using vs 2017 and ML.NET

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Comment: @devlincarnate no sadly the dlls required are there

Comment: Did you check the version, clean your solution, and the various other solutions listed in that post?

Comment: yes but to no avail

Comment: What other dependencies do you have in your project? Would you mind adding your .csproj file