# Could not load the dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, command-line-interface, clr

I am getting the below Exception but the project has built successfully; but, during Execution, it is not able to pick the required DLL.

> could not load a file or assembly 
>       "name_cli.dll" or one of its dependencies . the specified module could not be found.

May I know what could be the reason for the Issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Comment: Not all dlls are the same.  There are three basic types of dlls 1) Prior to WinXp.  These are not compatible with c# and will not run.  You need a c++ wrapper to execute these dlls 2) Non Managed from WinXp to present.  Need to call using DllImport 3) Managed Dlls and can be referenced directly from c#.  These three types also have sub types like X86, AnyCPU, x64.

Comment: @jdweng Would you share some url or links to get to know more about the C++ wrapper . I think my issue falls into the 2nd place

Comment: c++ code can be made to run from managed c#.  If you do not have managed c++ then you need to use DllImport.  There are lots of examples at www.pinvoke.net.  Pinvoke is a site that gives example code of running the Windows dlls (which are c++) from c#.

Comment: @jdweng There is nothing special about DLLs from XP and before. There's really just managed and unmanaged DLLs.

Comment: @Dheena thus first comment is the key one here, although it rather concentrates on managed DLLs. You'll want to install the appropriate MSVC runtime for this DLL, would be my guess.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan . Actually , I am using calling cli code from the c# project. cli code should be compatible with the c# right. I still don't see why there is a problem in loading a dll. Add your suggestions please .

Comment: Why do you ignore the first comment? And the thousands of other questions here that tell you same thing.