# Build passed locally but failed on jenkins server with system.servicemodel.faultexception could not load file or assembly and system.timeoutexception

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, jenkins, nunit

I have total 688 unit tests written in my project.
When I am running these unit tests on my local development environment then these all are passing successfully but when I am running these unit tests on Jenkins Server then 57 unit tests are failing out of 688.

I'm new in Jenkins so I'm confused what to do with this because if these issue would come on my local environment then I will definitely try to fix it but in Jenkins, I'm not getting any clue, what to do.

below is the 2 full stack trace which is generating while building through Jenkins:

**1.)**

```
MESSAGE:
System.ServiceModel.FaultException : Could not load file or assembly 'Store.Common, 
Version=21.1.4766.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bc4823754db87e14' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
+++++++++++++++++++
STACK TRACE:

Server stack trace:
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& 
rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, 
ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, 
ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at Store.ExternalApi.Proxy.IDocumentHandlingService.Search(SearchRequest request)
at Store.ExternalApi.Proxy.IDocumentHandlingService.Search(SearchRequest request) in 
D:\Dev\Server\mainline\ExternalApi\ExternalApiProxy\DocumentHandlingServiceClient.cs:line 416
at Store.ExternalApi.Tests.WebService.DestroyTests.DestroySearchWebMethod() in 
D:\Dev\Server\mainline\ExternalApi\ExternalApiTests\WebService\DestroyTests.cs:line 26
```

**2.)**

```
MESSAGE:
System.TimeoutException : The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 
00:00:59.9990195. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the 
SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a 
longer timeout.
  ----> System.TimeoutException : The HTTP request to 
'http://localhost/ExternalApiWebService/DocumentHandlingService.svc' has exceeded the allotted 
timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
+++++++++++++++++++
STACK TRACE:

Server stack trace:
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, 
ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, 
ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at Store.ExternalApi.Proxy.IDocumentHandlingService.
StoreNewVersionedDocument(StoreNewVersionedDocumentRequest request)

at Store.ExternalApi.Proxy.DocumentHandlingServiceClient.
Store.ExternalApi.Proxy.IDocumentHandlingService.
StoreNewVersionedDocument(StoreNewVersionedDocumentRequest request) in 
D:\Dev\Server\mainline\ExternalApi\ExternalApiProxy\DocumentHandlingServiceClient.cs:line 80
```

**Below is my web.config file of ExternalAPI project:**

```
<basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name="DocumentHandlingHttpsBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="01:10:00" 
maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="536870912" 
/>
        </binding>
</basicHttpsBinding>
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DocumentHandlingHttpBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="01:10:00" 
maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="536870912" 
/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="TransferServiceHttpBinding" sendTimeout="00:25:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807" transferMode="Streamed">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="536870912" 
/>
           <security>
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
           </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="TransferServiceWindowsHttpBinding" sendTimeout="01:10:00" 
maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807" transferMode="Streamed">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="536870912" 
/>
           <security>
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
           </security>
        </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
<netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="DocumentHandlingTcpBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="01:10:00" 
maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="536870912" 
/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="StoreTcpBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="01:10:00" 
maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="536870912" 
/>
           <security mode="Message">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
           </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="StoreWindowsTcpBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="01:10:00" 
maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="536870912" 
/>
           <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
           </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="TransferServiceTcpBinding" sendTimeout="01:10:00" transferMode="Streamed" 
maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="536870912" 
/>
           <security mode="None">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
           </security>
        </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="StoreHttpBinding" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="536870912" 
/>
           <security>
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
           </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="StoreWindowsHttpBinding" sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="536870912" 
/>
           <security>
              <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
           </security>
        </binding>
        <!--HTTPS-->
        <binding name="StoreHttpsBinding" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="104857600" 
/>
           <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="true" 
algorithmSuite="Default" />
           </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="StoreWindowsHttpsBinding" sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="104857600" 
/>
           <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
              <message clientCredentialType="Windows" algorithmSuite="Default" />
           </security>
        </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

**Below is ExternalAPITest.config file:**
**My all unit test cases are written in ExternalAPITest project:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
       <configSections>
          <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
             <section name="Store.ExternalApi.Tests.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
          </sectionGroup>
       </configSections>
       <applicationSettings>
          <Store.ExternalApi.Tests.Properties.Settings>
             <setting name="StoreUserName" serializeAs="String">
                <value>syspassword</value>
             </setting>
             <setting name="StorePassword" serializeAs="String">
                <value>syspassword</value>
             </setting>
          </Store.ExternalApi.Tests.Properties.Settings>
       </applicationSettings>
       <system.serviceModel>
          <behaviors>
             <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="StoreClientEndpointBehaviour">
                   <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="104857600" />
                   <clientCredentials>
                      <serviceCertificate>
                         <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
                      </serviceCertificate>
                   </clientCredentials>
                </behavior>
             </endpointBehaviors>
          </behaviors>
          <bindings>
             <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="DocumentHandlingServiceBinding" />
                <binding name="TransferServiceHttpBinding" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                  maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807"
                  transferMode="Streamed">
                   <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600"
                     maxArrayLength="536870912" />
                   <security>
                      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                   </security>
                </binding>
             </basicHttpBinding>
             <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="StoreHttpBinding" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                   <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="104857600"/>
                   <security>
                      <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
                   </security>
                </binding>
             </wsHttpBinding>
          </bindings>
          <client>
             <!-- new API service -->
             <endpoint address="http://localhost/ExternalApiWebService/DocumentHandlingService.svc"
               binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DocumentHandlingServiceBinding"
               contract="IDocumentHandlingService" name="DocumentHandlingService" />
    <!-- internal API services so that tests can talk to Store directly -->
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/AuthorizationManager/"
           behaviorConfiguration="StoreClientEndpointBehaviour" binding="wsHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="StoreHttpBinding" contract="Store.IAuthorizationManager"
           name="AuthorizationManagerHttp">
            <identity>
               <certificate encodedValue="cvpnc2MzsCp/KG6qFpMVEC3XXX" />
            </identity>
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/ConfigurationManager/"
           behaviorConfiguration="StoreClientEndpointBehaviour" binding="wsHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="StoreHttpBinding" contract="Store.IConfigurationManager2"
           name="ConfigurationManagerHttp">
            <identity>
               <certificate encodedValue="AwAAAAEAAAAUAAAAr4cvpnc2MzsCp/KG6qFpMVEC3XXX
            </identity>
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/DataDefinitionManager/"
           behaviorConfiguration="StoreClientEndpointBehaviour" binding="wsHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="StoreHttpBinding" contract="Store.IDataDefinitionManager2"
           name="DataDefinitionManagerHttp">
            <identity>
               <certificate encodedValue="cvpnc2MzsCp/KG6qFpMVEC3XXX
            </identity>
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/DataDefinitionManager/"
           behaviorConfiguration="StoreClientEndpointBehaviour" binding="wsHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="StoreHttpBinding" contract="Store.IFieldTypeManager"
           name="FieldTypeManagerHttp">
            <identity>
               <certificate encodedValue="cvpnc2MzsCp/KG6qFpMVEC3XXX
            </identity>
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/DataItemManager/"
           behaviorConfiguration="StoreClientEndpointBehaviour" binding="wsHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="StoreHttpBinding" contract="Store.IDataItemManager4"
           name="DataItemManagerHttp">
            <identity>
               <certificate encodedValue="cvpnc2MzsCp/KG6qFpMVEC3XXX
            </identity>
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/InternalDocumentHandlingService"
           behaviorConfiguration="StoreClientEndpointBehaviour" binding="wsHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="StoreHttpBinding" contract="Store.ExternalApi.IInternalDocumentHandlingService"
           name="InternalDocumentHandlingServiceHttp">
            <identity>
               <certificate encodedValue="cvpnc2MzsCp/KG6qFpMVEC3XXX
            </identity>
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/MembershipManager/"
           behaviorConfiguration="StoreClientEndpointBehaviour" binding="wsHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="StoreHttpBinding" contract="Store.IMembershipManager"
           name="MembershipManagerHttp">
            <identity>
               <certificate encodedValue="cvpnc2MzsCp/KG6qFpMVEC3XXX
            </identity>
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/SearchTemplateManager/"
           behaviorConfiguration="StoreClientEndpointBehaviour" binding="wsHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="StoreHttpBinding" contract="Store.ISearchTemplateManager6"
           name="SearchTemplateManagerHttp">
            <identity>
               <certificate encodedValue="cvpnc2MzsCp/KG6qFpMVEC3XXX
            </identity>
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/StorageManager/"
           behaviorConfiguration="StoreClientEndpointBehaviour" binding="wsHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="StoreHttpBinding" contract="Store.IStorageManager"
           name="StorageManagerHttp">
            <identity>
               <certificate encodedValue="cvpnc2MzsCp/KG6qFpMVEC3XXX
            </identity>
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/TransferService/" behaviorConfiguration="StoreClientEndpointBehaviour"
           binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransferServiceHttpBinding"
           contract="HitecLabs.TransferManager.Common.ITransferService"
           name="TransferService">
            <identity>
               <certificate encodedValue="cvpnc2MzsCp/KG6qFpMVEC3XXX
            </identity>
         </endpoint>
      </client>
   </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I tried increasing **SendTimeOut** but no luck,I have searched the relevant answers from google but it didn't helped in my case.

Can anyone suggest me, please ?

Comment: What is Store.Common and how do you use it in your server code?

Comment: @KlausGütter ,

Thank you for reply.
In my development environment, I am working on three solutions. StoreClient , StoreServer and StoreCommon.
So, here if any changes made in common it is impacting all three solutions which I am using.
here, Store.Common is a dll which is being used in Server solutions.

Please let me know, if any more information.

Comment: @KlausGütter , 
I am using this dll in my ExternalAPITest project as a reference.
Please suggest, if you have any idea ?

Comment: Can you provide more detailed configuration information? I want to know what binding your endpoint uses.

Comment: @Dingpeng ,
Hi,
I have added detailed configuration information for my ExternalAPITest project in asked queastion.
I have a project named ExternalAPI and I have created a Unit test project which name is ExternalAPITest.
And currently I have updated detailed configuration file for my ExternalAPITest project above.
Please have a look

Comment: @Dingpeng,
Please let me know if any more information required.

Comment: Do you configure the MSBuild .Net Plugin in Jenkins?I suspect it's about this.

Comment: @Dingpeng,
I have checked the configuration in Managed Jenkins section and found that "Jenkins MSBuild Plugin" is configured there.

Comment: You can refer to this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies.The questions in this link are similar to yours

Comment: Ok. I will check this.