# HRESULT: 0x80131040 : Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have strange symptoms in my project

HRESULT: 0x80131040 occured 
[Microsoft.Azure.Amqp, **Version=2.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35']

```
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Azure.Amqp" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.3.0.0" />
```

No problem in my PC environment(Win10)
also Win7

Problems arise in different device(Win10).

I tried to upgrade Nuget version, but prob still remain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Application.exe

In case [Problems arise in different device(Win10).]
There is no Application.exe.config file

I attached additional config file, it worked.

but still wonder why this problem doesn't  arise at Win7(No config file)...