# Publish in Azure: Mismatch dependency error. What is causing it and how to fix it when using publishing via a pipeline?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-pipelines

When I run for the first time or publish my project to a web-server via Visual Studio I get sometimes this type of error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I can fix it by running the following command in the console and running or publishing again

> Update-Package –reinstall Package.Name

I wonder what is the reason for this error and how could I fix it if I am publishing through a pipeline and therefore I cannot run the command in the console when it fails.

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [assembly Binding Log Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/e74a18c4(v=vs.71)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). It should give you more details about the problem.

We could also find the referenced assembly in `Solution Explorer` and in the `Properties` window, set the field `Copy Local` to `True`. It should also fix this issue.

In the Azure DevOps, since you have fix this issue via the cmd `Update-Package –reinstall Package.Name`, we could also add the task Command as the first task and enter the cmd `Update-Package –reinstall Package.Name` to reinstall the package.

Please also check this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies).