# ExcelDataReader not working in Class Library project

Tags: exceldatareader

Receiving the following error when trying to run a Server Process, class library project:

"ERROR : Error (0) Could not load file or assembly 'ExcelDataReader, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=93517dbe6a4012fa' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I have installed the respective ExcelDataReader and ExcelDataReder.DataSet packages via NuGet.

You can see all is loaded in the following screenshot:

[Visual Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8mEm.png)

Any suggestions most welcome, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi! This is typically a general problem with VS or your project file and not the dependency itself. Did you try to restart VS? This answer has plenty suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Comment: Yes, I tried many suggested ideas, but no joy. BUT I did find a suitable Excel library which has worked first time, thanks to the peeps at GemBox.

Answer (score -2):

I can 100% recommend the GemBox Excel solution. This works perfectly in my .net standard 2.0 library solution.

https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet