# Visual Studio versioning is different that what was installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, system.json

I am working on a project in C# and multiple times I have installed nuget packages and put the latest version but then I get errors that it can't find a completely different version number.

Here is one nuget package that I had this problem with:

[Version I installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1h39.png)

and this is the version that is added to my project:

[Version in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Hky.png)

I am not sure why this is happening but if anyone has had this issue how have you fixed it? The way I've looked up how to fix this was not bringing me any results. Thank you

Edit: thought id also show the error my service gets from it when starting

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXwLt.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Comment: `it cant find a completely different versioning number` - Well that is a completely different versioning number. *4.7.1* is the [NuGet package version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning), whereas *2.0.8.0* is the [Assembly version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/versioning)