# XC1020: Build error occurred in the XAML MSBuild task: 'Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       XC1020: Build error occurred in the XAML MSBuild task: 'Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Projects\DIB\IB\Dev\MAIN\Source\Business\VBMService\bin\evohtmltopdf.dll' or one of its dependencies. Modules which are not in the manifest were streamed in. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131043)' VBMService

**evohtmltopdf.dll is present in VBMServices**

Comment: I needs to be present in the bin folder.

Comment: its there in bin folder but still am getting this error @AliK

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies) might help