# ASP.NET Core - How to resolve Could not load file or assembly 'Bricelam.EntityFrameworkCore.Pluralizer,

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.Net Core-7 Web API Application, I am implemeting Database First Approach because I have existing database.

So I iran Install-Package Bricelam.EntityFrameworkCore.Pluralizer   --ver 1.0.0

My Infrastructure.proj is as shown below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Bricelam.EntityFrameworkCore.Pluralizer" Version="1.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.27.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.27.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Domain\Models\" />
    <Folder Include="Persistence\DbContexts\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I did this:

PM> Scaffold-DbContext -Connection Name=CoreDbConnection Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir Persistence/DbContexts -OutputDir Domain/Models -Context CoreDbContext -Tables exams, teacher, student -force

I got this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Bricelam.EntityFrameworkCore.Pluralizer, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies check here

Comment: 2 simple steps fix most of these issues:
delete /bin and /obj folders from your projects und restore your nuget packages

Comment: Have you try to reopen the project?