# Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.IndexAttribute' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm experiencing an issue when I try to debug my ASP.NET MVC project in .NET 4.8 using IIS Express.

```
[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.IndexAttribute' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.]
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +195
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +196
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) +156
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +630
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimePropertyInfo property, RuntimeType caType) +106
   System.Attribute.InternalGetCustomAttributes(PropertyInfo element, Type type, Boolean inherit) +41
   System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(MemberInfo element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) +15
   System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute(MemberInfo element, Boolean inherit) +56
   AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions.<>c.<GetMatchingMemberInfo>b__2_0(MemberInfo sourceMember) +37
   System.Linq.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() +121
   System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +259
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +215
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +51
   AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions.SourceToDestinationNameMapperAttributesMember.GetMatchingMemberInfo(IGetTypeInfoMembers getTypeInfoMembers, TypeDetails typeInfo, Type destType, Type destMemberType, String nameToSearch) +451
   AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions.ParentSourceToDestinationNameMapper.GetMatchingMemberInfo(TypeDetails typeInfo, Type destType, Type destMemberType, String nameToSearch) +164
   AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions.DefaultMember.MapDestinationPropertyToSource(ProfileMap options, TypeDetails sourceType, Type destType, Type destMemberType, String nameToSearch, LinkedList`1 resolvers, IMemberConfiguration parent) +78
   AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions.MemberConfiguration.MapDestinationPropertyToSource(ProfileMap options, TypeDetails sourceType, Type destType, Type destMemberType, String nameToSearch, LinkedList`1 resolvers) +181
   AutoMapper.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<MapDestinationPropertyToSource>b__0(IMemberConfiguration _) +67
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +182
   AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory.CreateTypeMap(Type sourceType, Type destinationType, ProfileMap options) +364
   AutoMapper.ProfileMap.BuildTypeMap(TypeMapRegistry typeMapRegistry, ITypeMapConfiguration config) +99
   AutoMapper.ProfileMap.Register(TypeMapRegistry typeMapRegistry) +243
   AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.Seal() +279
   AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor(MapperConfigurationExpression configurationExpression) +1018
   AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(Action`1 config) +46
   Clubr.Web.LandingPage.App_Start.AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings() in E:\Farhad\Repositories\clbrr\Source\Clubr.Web.LandingPage\App_Start\AutoMapperConfig.cs:10
   Clubr.Web.LandingPage.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in E:\Farhad\Repositories\clbrr\Source\Clubr.Web.LandingPage\Startup.cs:25

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +216
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +182
   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass18_1.<MakeDelegate>b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +93
   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<LoadImplementation>b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +224
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) +897
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +51
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +101
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +139
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +160
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +584
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +719
```

[Click to view exception shot in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afXlg.png)

I tried upgrading EF to a newer version and using Local IIS, but the problem still persists.

Would downgrading Visual Studio to an earlier version be a possible solution? (I am using the latest version)

Seeking assistance in fixing this.

Comment: As the error message clearly states, the version of the type you want to use is not in the assembly you said it's in. Unfortunately there are many many situations that could cause that. Start by reading through [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4469929/22437).

Answer (score 0):

You have a dependency conflict. `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.IndexAttribute` [requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) EntityFramework 6.2. It's not part of EntityFramework 6.0. That means some part of your code is referencing the newer framework while the actual binaries in the target folder are still old. You must make sure you use the latest version of EntityFramework.dll/nuget across your solution.

Comment: all projects of the solution have EF 6.4 installed. click to see: https://imgur.com/a/PeU41H7

Comment: Sometimes, there's a bit of confusion about the version numbers (e.g. the dll version of EF could still be 6.0 even if the nuget package has a never version), but you should check whether the file in the 6.4 package is actually the one that ends up in your bin folder.

Comment: I have just cleaned the solution, removed the bin and obj folders of the projects, and rebuilt it. ef dlls are correct and the problem exists. https://imgur.com/a/EXMuiWn