# asp.net connection class Compiler Error Message: CS1001: Identifier expected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having  problems with errors in my connection class file while is breaking the rest of my website.
the error message i get when i  try to preview my tours.aspx page:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1001: Identifier expected **Line19**

**here is the code for my connection class file.**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Entities;

public static class ConnectionClass
{
    private static SqlConnection conn;
    private static SqlCommand command;

    static ConnectionClass()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["toursConnection"].ToString();
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        command = new SqlCommand("", conn);
    }

    #region tours
    public static tours GettoursByID(int)
    {
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM tours WHERE id =  '{0}'", id);
        tours tours = null;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.CommandText = query;
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string name = reader.GetString(1);
                string date = reader.GetString(2);
                double price = reader.GetDouble(3);
                string venue = reader.GetString(4);
                string country = reader.GetString(5);
                string image = reader.GetString(6);
                string description = reader.GetString(7);

                tours = new tours(id, name, date, price, venue, country, image, description);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return tours;
    }

    public static ArrayList GettoursByType(string toursType)
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM tours WHERE type LIKE '{0}'", toursType);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.CommandText = query;
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                string name = reader.GetString(1);
                string type = reader.GetString(2);
                double price = reader.GetDouble(3);
                string roast = reader.GetString(4);
                string country = reader.GetString(5);
                string image = reader.GetString(6);
                string review = reader.GetString(7);

                tours tours = new tours(id, name, type, price, roast, country, image, review);
                list.Add(tours);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return list;
    }

    public static void Addtours(tours tours)
    {
        string query = string.Format(
            @"INSERT INTO tours VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', @prices, '{2}', '{3}','{4}', '{5}')",
            tours.Name, tours.date, tours.venue, tours.Country, tours.Image, tours.description);
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prices", tours.Price));
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            command.Parameters.Clear();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Users
    public static User LoginUser(string name, string password)
    {
        //Check if user exists
        string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toursDB.dbo.users WHERE name = '{0}'", name);
        command.CommandText = query;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            int amountOfUsers = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

            if (amountOfUsers == 1)
            {
                //User exists, check if the passwords match
                query = string.Format("SELECT password FROM users WHERE name = '{0}'", name);
                command.CommandText = query;
                string dbPassword = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                if (dbPassword == password)
                {
                    //Passwords match. Login and password data are known to us.
                    //Retrieve further user data from the database
                    query = string.Format("SELECT email, user_type FROM users WHERE name = '{0}'", name);
                    command.CommandText = query;

                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    User user = null;

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string email = reader.GetString(0);
                        string type = reader.GetString(1);

                        user = new User(name, password, email, type);
                    }
                    return user;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Passwords do not match
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //User does not exist
                return null;
            }
        }
        finally
        {

            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    public static string RegisterUser(User user)
    {
        //Check if user exists
        string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name = '{0}'", user.Name);
        command.CommandText = query;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            int amountOfUsers = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

            if (amountOfUsers < 1)
            {
                //User does not exist, create a new user
                query = string.Format("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}')", user.Name, user.Password,
                                      user.Email, user.Type);
                command.CommandText = query;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return "User registered!";
            }
            else
            {
                //User exists
                return "A user with this name already exists";
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    #endregion

        #region Orders
        public static void AddOrder(ArrayList orders)
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO orders VALUES (@client, @productName, @amount, @price, @date, @orderSent)";
                conn.Open();

                foreach (Order order in orders)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@client", order.Client));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@productName", order.ProductName));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@amount", order.Amount));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@price", order.Price));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date", order.Date));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@orderSent", order.OrderSent));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 

-->
```

**this is my web confif file** 
   <

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 

-->
<configuration>
  <appSettings />
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="toursConnection" connectionString="Data Source=LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CoffeeDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CoffeeDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CoffeeDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <!-- 

        -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--

        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <!--

        </customErrors>
        -->
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <!-- 

    -->
</configuration>
```

**tours.aspx.cs code below**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using Entities;

namespace Pages
{
    public partial class Pages_tours : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillPage();
        }

        private void FillPage()
        {
            ArrayList toursList = ConnectionClass.GettoursByType(!IsPostBack ? "%" : DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (tours tours in toursList)
            {
                sb.Append(
                    string.Format(
                        @"<table class='toursTable'>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan='6' width='150px'><img runat='server' src='{6}' /></th>
                <th width='50px'>Name: </td>
                <td>{0}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>Type: </th>
                <td>{1}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>Price: </th>
                <td>{2} $</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>Roast: </th>
                <td>{3}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>Origin: </th>
                <td>{4}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>{5}</td>
            </tr>           

           </table>",
                        tours.Name, tours.Type, tours.Price, tours.Roast, tours.Country, tours.Review, tours.Image));
            }
            lblOuput.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have your connection string inside your webconfig file?

Comment: @Jmac88 : try the solution in my answer and tell if it help.

Comment: so you have two database for that single project?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this line

```
public static tours GettoursByID(int)
```

you must provide a name fro the parameter

```
public static tours GettoursByID(int id)
```

Comment: mow i get an error on the tours.aspx.cs  file but i dont know where to find that file.

Comment: @Jmac88 : I think you have multiple errors after fixing one the other raise!.

Comment: @Jmac88 : can't find it. be sure you saved changeds

Comment: @Jmac88 : have a look at this post, It seems to be like your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671747/inherit-problem-in-asp-net

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6092a65fba7f0667a8e4f8669953341b that is the error i get when trying to run tours.aspx  file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109253/discussion-between-jmac88-and-ahmedsafan86).